# going to first div after scroll going to top of the last div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem with scrolling.
When clicking on `<a href="#" id="display" class="display">next</a>` tag,
page scrolls to next `div`. When scrolling to top of the last `div` and then clicking "next", it must go to the top of the first `div`, but it doesn't.

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code:

```
  if (t === 'next' ) {
    if($('.current').next('.section').length==0)
    var $next = $('#one');
    else
    var $next = $('.current').next('.section');
  }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/272/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
if (t === 'next') {

    var $next = $('.current').next('.section');

    //so no more next
    if (!$next.length)
        $next = $('div.section').first();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/270/